# What tools would I need to have/borrow/buy to build a table?

Tags: tools, carpentry

What are the types of tools that I would need to have access to in order to build something like a table from wood?

Comment: What type of table? How fancy/complex would you like the table to be?  You could build a table by placing plywood on saw horses, in which case no tools are needed (aside from saw horses).

Comment: Was going to try to build a 4'x6' table with room for many people to sit around, storage areas for game pieces, built-in cupholders, etc.

Comment: You should update your question with more detail, maybe a sketch of what you have in mind.  Your level of carpentry skill might also help, as some techniques are more advanced than others.

Comment: If you have to ask what tools you need to build a table, I'm not sure this is a project you want to tackle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends in no small part on how you wish to construct the table.  For instance, if you wish to do a simple screw or nail construction, it's a different set of end tools than if you wanted to do dove-tail joints, or biscuit joints, or mortice and tenant joints...

**The basics (screw construction)**

- Measuring tape
- Pencils
- A straight edge (usually part of a related
  tool)
- A saw
- A drill (for pre drilling screw holes)
- A screwdriver or driver bit for your drill - for installing the screws
- Several grits of sand paper from coarse (60 grit) to ultra fine (220 grit)
- A sanding block (flat surface used to keep your sand paper flat)